# return ModelAndView when JSON is returned

Tags: json, jsp, spring-mvc

Can we return JSON object from spring controller and write that JSON object on jsp page.
Below is my jsp page:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
 dojo.require("dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid");
            dojo.require("dojox.data.QueryReadStore");
  dojo.ready(function(){

                mystore=new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({url:"<%=request.getContextPath()%>/showData.htm"});

                 var layout= [
                 {field: 'ID', name: 'SID',formatter: hrefFormatter,datatype:"number" },
                 {field: 'SPREAD',name: 'SPREAD',autoComplete: true}
]
 var grid = new dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid({
                        id: 'myGrid',
                       ----
                        });
</script>
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/showData", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void getSTIDData(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, @ModelAttribute VINDTO vinData,
            BindingResult beException) throws IOException {
        try {
              ......
              ......
             XStream xstream = new XStream(new JsonHierarchicalStreamDriver() {
                public HierarchicalStreamWriter createWriter(Writer writer) {
                    return new JsonWriter(writer, JsonWriter.DROP_ROOT_MODE);
                }
            });

            xstream.alias("items", com.loans.auto.DTO.VINRequestDTO.class);
            String str = xstream.toXML(vinListCopy);

            StringBuffer rowData = new StringBuffer();
            rowData.append("{'numRows':").append(vinListCopy.size())
                    .append(",'items':").append(str).append("}");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.print(rowData);
}
```

Instead of getSTIDData(..) returning void , i want this method to return ModelAndView object, but when i return ModelAndView object, in jsp page data is not getting loaded and it says "NO Data Found". Please suggest. Thanks.

Below is the exception generated when i used Gson

```
SyntaxError {stack: "SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier↵    at Object.d… at signalWaiting (/MYWebProject/dojo/Deferred.js:28:4)", message: "Unexpected identifier"}
message: "Unexpected identifier"
stack: "SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier↵    at Object.dojo.fromJson (/MYWebProject/dojo/_base/json.js:26:23)↵    at Object.dojo._contentHandlers.dojo.contentHandlers.json (/MYWebProject/dojo/_base/xhr.js:78:16)↵    at Object.dojo._contentHandlers.dojo.contentHandlers.json-comment-optional (/MYWebProject/dojo/_base/xhr.js:156:28)↵    at _deferredOk (/MYWebProject/dojo/_base/xhr.js:432:42)↵    at notify (/MYWebProject/dojo/_base/Deferred.js:187:23)↵    at complete (/MYWebProject/dojo/_base/Deferred.js:168:4)↵    at resolve.callback (/MYWebProject/dojo/_base/Deferred.js:248:4)↵    at eval (/MYWebProject/dojo/_base/xhr.js:627:8)↵    at signalListener (/MYWebProject/dojo/Deferred.js:37:21)↵    at signalWaiting (/MYWebProject/dojo/Deferred.js:28:4)"
__proto__: Error
```

Comment: If you use Jackson, you can simply add a `ObjectMapper` to the model and write any other object as a JSON string.

Comment: I think you're looking for [@ResponseBody](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestBody.html).

Answer (score 1):

yes you can return as JSON response.showing with the help of Gson API

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/showData", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String getUserHomePage(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response, @ModelAttribute VINDTO vinData,BindingResult beException) throws IOException {
//you code stuff to create model object bean
Gson gson = new  Gson();
return gson.toJson(objectBean);
}
```

Comment: iam getting exception on broswer console,please see the initial post edited @Abhishek Mishra.

Comment: gson.toJson(rowData);
is wrong code ,create one class as xyz set all the value what you want with setter method and then pass xyz object say xyzobj to gson
like
return gson.toJson(xyzobj);

Comment: ok , i will try. one more question can i return any exception page if condition fails, as from my original code i was unable to do that, i believe even with this code what we are talking we cannot return to exception page if any exception occurs, as this class is only loading the data inside dojo gird but the grid is already loaded, thats the reason when i got any kind of exception its only showing "NO DATA FOUND" inside dojo grid instead of forwarding to error page @Abhishek Mishra.

Comment: if your action class need to return jSon response then you can't redirect to error page from controller ,but you can send error response in json and then redirect to error page once you received to error response.

Comment: Oh ok. then i think i need to do lot of changes in my jsp page, please see the jsp page posted in the initial post. currently iam not handling anything at the jsp page.Is that correct? @Abhishek Mishra

Comment: i think there is no jsp page ,only i have seen script

Comment: That script does all the thing. i dont have any extra jsp code to show the data. from controller we are printing the response and that script does print the data on the screen. thanks for ur time and voted :) @Abhishek Mishra.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it clean and simple...

Here is a real life snippet of code ...

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/actions/getImplGroups", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<String> getImplGroups(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

        List<String> groups = bpmClient.getAllGroups();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String jsonString;
        try {
            jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(groups);
        } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
            jsonString = "Error with json generation: " + e.getMessage();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            jsonString = "Error with json mapping: " + e.getMessage();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            jsonString = "Error with json: " + e.getMessage();
        }

        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        responseHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(jsonString, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

The important point to consider is sending the correct web header, so that your page expects to see json.

I the case above we used the [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome) library to create the json, but in truth you could format the json any way you like.  Here is an example of a simple, manually formatted string...

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/actions/getTicketsNotUpdatedWithinShift", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> getTicketsNotUpdatedWithinShift(String center, String sections, String minutesInShift, Model model) {

    String[] sectionArray = sections.split(",");

    String json = "";
    String rowsString = "";

    for (String section : sectionArray) {
        List<Map<String, String>> rows = service.getMinutesSinceLastTicketUpdate(center, section);

        for (Map<String, String> row : rows) {
            int minutesSinceUpdate = Integer.parseInt(row.get("minutes"));

            if (minutesSinceUpdate > Integer.parseInt(minutesInShift)) {
                String description = row.get("description");
                rowsString = rowsString + "\"" + description + "\",";
            }
        }
    }

    // Build the json structure
    if (!rowsString.isEmpty()) {
        // Trim the trailing comma.
        rowsString = rowsString.replaceAll(",$", "");
        json = "[" + rowsString + "]";
    } else {
        json = "[]";
    }


    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    responseHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(json, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```